# Can't install puma gem on kali

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux

When I try to run this code:

`bundle install`

I got this error:

```
An error occurred while installing puma (3.6.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install puma -v '3.6.0'` succeeds before bundling.
```

and when I ran `gem install puma -v '3.6.0'` I got the error.

[Here](https://gist.github.com/Alavi1412/f15a767def104cd1abe8b43009448fe8) is `mkmf.log` file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try run following on your system.

> sudo apt-get install libssl1.0-dev

For more info look  [here](https://github.com/puma/puma/issues/1195)